# Read and Write Cookie in Symfony2

Tags: cookies, symfony

I want to store some information in the local browser cookie. After hours looking for a nice tutorial, I managed to store some data in a non-session cookie:

**controller - indexAction()**

```
$cookieGuest = array(
    'name'  => 'mycookie',
    'value' => 'testval',
    'path'  => $this->generateUrl('my_route'),
    'time'  => time() + 3600 * 24 * 7
);

$cookie = new Cookie($cookieGuest['name'], $cookieGuest['value'], $cookieGuest['time'], $cookieGuest['path']);

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
$response->send();
```

I wonder if this is the correct way. Furthermore I tried several ways to read the cookie with the HttpFoundation Component, but without success. Is there another way than accessing the cookie via **$_COOKIE['mycookie']** ?

Here is where I try to read the cookie

**controller - cookieAction()**

```
public function cookieAction($_locale, $branch, $page) 
{   
    $response = new Response();
    $cookies = $response->headers->getCookies();

    var_dump($cookies);

// TODO: Get params for indexAction from cookie if available

    return $this->indexAction($_locale, $branch, $page);
}
```

Comment: a closing quote is missing on `testval` (third row). I cannot edit it on your behalf because an edit needs 6 chars

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$response->headers->getCookies();
```

should return an array of cookies  look in ResponseHeaderBag class for more information about that function

Comment: This method returns a empty array.

Comment: Well, but I want to check the cookie values as soon as I request the main page, any idea?

Comment: i think you are mixing the response with the request, at that point you have an empty response. Try  `$request = $this->getRequest(); $request->cookies->all();`

Comment: In the most of cases it is not the right way of working with cookies. Look at my post below

Answer (score 78):

This is the correct way of setting cookie.
To read cookie already written in the browser do:

```
$request->cookies->get('myCookie');
```

But after I created cookie in the $response object:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('myCookie', 'contentOfMyCookie');
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

I call this method:

```
$response->headers->getCookies();
```

I get an array of cookies, which are to be written in the browser - not those already existing there.

Figuratively, between $request and $response there is a time of executing controller's code.

Besides, in a twig template you can use

```
{{ app.request.cookies.get('myCookie') }}
```

you thus get value of the cookie already written in the browser, not that from the $response object! Newly created cookie from the browser you can read only after having reloaded page (ajax doesn't need to reload whole page).

To sum it up, you can **read cookies** using **$request** object, and *create* them with *$response* object. (Obviously, for some reasons, you can also read $response object cookies - but these are rather rare situations).

Answer (score 17):

this can be useful for someone trying to make cookies in symfony2 :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
```

Answer (score 5):

Example how to use Cookies and Session:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Set session value
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->set('test', 1);

        // Get session value
        $value = $session->get('test');

        // Set cookie value
        $response = new Response();
        $cookie = new Cookie('test', 1, time()+3600);
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

        // Get cookie value
        $this->getRequest()->cookies->get('test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
            use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

            // set current active tab in cookie 
            $cookie = new Cookie('myProfileActiveTab', 'myaddress', strtotime('now + 60 minutes'));
            $response = new Response();
            $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
            $response->send();


           // get current active tab from cookies
           $cookies = $request->cookies;
           if ($cookies->has('myProfileActiveTab')) {
               $activetab = $cookies->get('myProfileActiveTab');
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

More interesting cookies information links (http_fundation component for symfony2):

[Symfony2 http_fundation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#setting-cookies)

[Symfony2 http_fundation api](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html#method_setCookie)

[Symfony2 http_fundation component (spanish)](http://gitnacho.github.com/symfony-docs-es/components/http_foundation.html)