# Fill a form with the username in the symfony2 session

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I want to build a form that can use the information stored in a session to set default field values. 
ie when a user wants to log in, the field **username** will be populated automatically with the username stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need to do is [Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) or even use a [Transformer in a custom field type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-transformers-in-a-custom-field-type).

I'm not super familiar with all Symfony2 features, but I assume you could pass a [session](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) or a [response object (to get a cookie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727442/read-and-write-cookie-in-symfony2) to the transformer. If the username is available it can be set as the field data, if is not set an empty string.