# session timeout in php symfony2 framework

Tags: php, symfony

i am using php with symfony 2 framework and IIS has the web server .
In my config file i have added the following code for timeout .

```
  session:
       cookie_lifetime: 36000 //time out is 10 hours
```

So if the cookie is disabled in user's machine will it affect the timeout or is cookie enabling really needed to timeout to work.
I am trying to add a timeout of 10 hrs for user if they have left the application idle.
Any feedback would be really helpfull.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Does `cookie_lifetime` not work?

Comment: my concern is if the cookies are disabled on user's machine will this approach work and user session will not timeout atleast for 10 hrs

Comment: No - user sessions won't work at all if the user disables cookies. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572134/php-sessions-with-disabled-cookies-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

In yuor case it's important to know details about what a cookie is (also it is interesting to understand about server side sessions).

Cookie -> Client side.
Session -> Server side.

http://www.phpcubes.com/what-is-the-difference-between-session-and-cookies.html

Cookies are client-side and depends on client browser configuration.

About Symfony cookie handling, check this post:

[Read and Write Cookie in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727442/read-and-write-cookie-in-symfony2)

I hope it will be useful for you.